# Нужна ли запятая перед "чтобы" или она необязательна?

Tags: пунктуация

Отдавать двадцать евро за то чтобы перекантоваться до утра, – не хотелось, залезать в островные дебри тоже желания не было: устал.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна для выделения придаточного, тире не нужно:

**Отдавать двадцать евро за то, чтобы перекантоваться до утра,  не хотелось, залезать в островные дебри тоже желания не было: устал.**

Comment: Однозначно? Но, когда я читаю предложение, паузу в месте предполагаемой запятой не делаю. Тире - для противопоставления первой части предложения - второй его части.

Comment: В русской пунктуации совместно действуют интонационный и грамматический принципы. Ориентироваться только на один принцип неверно.  В предложениях несложной структуры эти два принципа обычно успешно сосуществуют, но в сложных конструкциях делается перераспределение интонационных ударений и пауз.  В вашем предложении пауза пережд ЧТОБЫ действительно  отсутствует, так как  СПП в первой части воспринимается как единое целое, а ударение падает на слова "не хотелось", "тоже не было". В нем сложно сделать даже авторскую паузу перед "хотелось",  да и авторское тире после запятой трудно объяснить.

Comment: Если слышите предложение по-другому, надо перестраивать его структуру: Отдавать двадцать евро за нехитрый ночлег - не хотелось, залезать в островные дебри  - тоже желания не было: устал. В этом предложении использована авторская параллельная интонация и авторские тире.

Comment: Отдавать двадцать евро за ночлег (–)не хотелось, залезать в островные дебри (–) тоже желания не было: устал. Согласен. Но нужны ли в обновленном варианте тире?

Comment: В общем случае ставить тире, конечно,  не нужно, но в предложении  такой конструкции можно поставить авторское тире (если вы хотите сделать паузы при чтении). А в заданном  предложении  авторское тире невозможно. Такое тире, называемое интонационным, может отделять любую часть предложения, где не было знаков, а также может заменять запятую, но оно не используется совместно с запятой (закрывающей, например, придаточную часть). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=94#pp94